# How to select content without element using simplehtmldom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to extract data from a website using PHP with the help of simplehtmldom.

The problem is that there is a text which doesn't have any parent element.

```
<div class="div_1">First div</div> The text i need to grab <div class="div_2">Second div</div>
```

In the above demonstration i need to extract `The text i need to grab`.

Comment: simple can't target text nodes like that. I recommend you switch [to this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/) and do `$el->next`

Comment: Thanks @pguardiario, i will surely use advancedhtmldom

Answer (score -1):

If simplehtmldom is not required, try Regular Expressions:

```
<div[^<>]*class="div_1"[^<>]*>.*?</div>(.*?)<div[^<>]*class="div_2"[^<>]*>.*?</div>
```

http://regexr.com/3bd5f

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try to integrate this with simplehtmldom as it is required.